# PyGame polygon, using a tuple as a parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, polygon

I want to draw a polygon on screen, like so:

```
coords = (653,333),(680,444),(680,444),(653,445)
pygame.draw.polygon(screen, (0, 0, 255), coords, 0)
```

however this does not draw to the screen. Any help appreciated.

ANSWER: coords should be a list of tuples, so for my example the correct answer would be:

```
coords = [(653,333), (680,444), (680,444), (653,445)]
pygame.draw.polygon(screen, (0, 0, 255), coords, 0)
```

Comment: What's the error? what do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: Are you maybe drawing it outside of the screen? What's the size of the `screen`? Take a look at this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry, my original format was poorly worded, have updated it now though.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue. If you can, please make an [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. I suspect that in trying to make one, you'll figure out what is going wrong on your end (you probably have a typo or something in your code that you've not reproduced in your question here).

Comment: If DobromirM's answer didn't fix the problem, you have to provide a complete and runnable example, so that we can test it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you gave seems to be correct. I've tested it and it displays a triangle. As suggested by [skrx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6220679/skrx) in the comment your screen size is too small and you are not able to see it.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
BLUE = (0,   0, 255)
size = [1920, 1080]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
    clock.tick(10)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    temp = (653, 333), (680, 444), (680, 444), (653, 445)
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, BLUE, temp, 0)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, I didn't specify my problem very well. Why is it when I use 'temp' in the draw.polygon function, the outcome is different to me just putting the contents of 'temp' into the draw.polygon function?

Comment: If you put them like that `pygame.draw.polygon(screen, BLUE, [(653, 333), (680, 444), (680, 444), (653, 445)], 0)` there should be no difference. If you don't surround them with `[]` it treats them as separate arguments to the `.polygon` function and thus resulting in a different behavior.